# Automating Validation of PDF Prepared Reports

Tags: validation, pdf, automation, analytics, spotfire

Our team uses Spotfire to host online analyses and also prepare monthly reports. One pain point that we have is around validation. The reports are all prepared reports, and the process for creating them each month is as simple as 1) refresh the data (through Infolink connected to Oracle) and 2) Press button to export each report. The format of the final product is a PDF.

The issue is that there are a lot of small things that can go wrong with the reports (filter accidentally applied, wrong month selected, data didn't refresh, new department not grouped correctly, etc.) meaning that someone on our team has to manually validate each of the reports. We create almost 20 reports each month and some of them are as many as 100 pages.

We've done a great job automating the creation of the reports, but now we have this weird imbalance where it takes like 25 minutes to create all the reports but 4+ hours to validate each one.

Does anyone know of a good way to automate, or even cut down, the time we have to spend each month validating the reports? I did a brief google and all I could find was in the realm of validating reports to meet government regulation standards

Answer (score 0):

It depends on 2 factors:

1. Do your reports have the same template (format) each time you extract them? You said that you pull them out automatically so I guess the answer is Yes.
2. What exactly are you trying to check/validate? You need to have a clear list on what are you validating. You mentioned month, grouping, data values (for the refresh)). But the clearer the picture you have for validation, the more likely the process can be fully automated.

There are so called RPA (robot process automation) tools that can automate complex workflows.
A "data extract" task, which is part of a workflow, can detect and collect data from documents (PDF for example).
A robot that runs on the validating machine can:

- batch read all your PDF reports from specified locations on your computer (or on another computer);
- based on predefined templates it can read through the documents for specific fields that you specify (through defined anchors on the templates) and collect the exact data from there;
- compare the extracted data with the baseline that you set (compare the month to be correct, compare a data field to confirm proper refresh of the data, another data field to confirm grouping, etc.);
  It takes a bit of time to dissect the PDF for each report template and correctly set the anchors but then it runs seamless each time.

One such tool I used is called [Atomatik](https://www.atomatik.com). It has a studio environment where you design the robot (or robots) and run the process.